# Message "‘CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE’ was not declared in this scope" in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv

The version is 3.0.0. I didn't code the sources and I'm not a C++ expert.

I tried compiling the first time, and had to change from `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` to `cv::IMREAD_COLOR`, then `CV_YCrCb2BGR` to `cv::COLOR_YCrCb2BGR` (and did the same for other color conversions).

Now it says `CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE` wasn't declared, but I don't know what to do next and couldn't find the answer online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd like to set the shape of [`getStructuringElement`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=structuringelement#getstructuringelement).

It has been changed to `cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE`. `CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE` was one of a structuring element's shape for morphological operations in the old OpenCV 1.x API.

Comment: Great knowledge, I couldn't find this answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment in `opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h`:

```
/** Shapes of a structuring element for morphological operations
@see cv::MorphShapes, cv::getStructuringElement
*/
enum MorphShapes_c
{
    CV_SHAPE_RECT      =0,
    CV_SHAPE_CROSS     =1,
    CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE   =2,
    CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM    =100 //!< custom structuring element
};
```

`CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSIS` is now `MORPH_ELLIPSE.`, which is defined in `opencv2/imgproc.hpp`:

```
//! shape of the structuring element
enum MorphShapes {
    MORPH_RECT    = 0, //!< a rectangular structuring element:  \f[E_{ij}=1\f]
    MORPH_CROSS   = 1, //!< a cross-shaped structuring element:
                       //!< \f[E_{ij} =  \fork{1}{if i=\texttt{anchor.y} or j=\texttt{anchor.x}}{0}{otherwise}\f]
    MORPH_ELLIPSE = 2 //!< an elliptic structuring element, that is, a filled ellipse inscribed
                      //!< into the rectangle Rect(0, 0, esize.width, 0.esize.height)
};
```